# Is it possible to add items to a Go channel while processing?

Tags: go

I am trying to find a way to recursively work through a task in Go using goroutines. The goal of the program is to take an input element into a channel and add to an output channel input -1 until 0 is reached. The number of workers processing should be adaptable. The process I am following is as so:

Create an input an output channel. Add the starting number to the input channel. Initialize workers to run the worker function. Loop through and print the outputs in the output channel.

```
func main() {
    inputChannel := make(chan int, 1)
    outputChannel := make(chan int)
    inputChannel <- 100
    numWorkers := 4
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(inputChannel, outputChannel)
    }
    for elem := range outputChannel {
        fmt.Println("Output: ", elem)
    }
}
```

Next, in the order function, we loop through the elements in the input channel, checking each time if there are more elements to receive. If there are more elements to receive, we print the input element, subtract 1 from the element and send to the input channel for another worker to pick up if the element is greater than 0. If there is nothing left in the input channel then we return.

```
func worker(input chan int, output chan<- int) {
    defer close(input)
    defer close(output)
    for {
        element, more := <-input
        if more {
            fmt.Println("Input: ", element)
            element--
            if element != 0 {
                input <- element
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println("All Jobs Processed")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am seeing is:

```
Input:  100
Input:  99
Input:  98
Input:  97
Input:  96
Input:  95
Input:  94
Input:  93
Input:  92
Input:  91
Input:  90
Input:  89
Input:  88
Input:  87
Input:  86
Input:  85
Input:  84
Input:  83
Input:  82
Input:  81
Input:  80
Input:  79
Input:  78
Input:  77
Input:  76
Input:  75
Input:  74
Input:  73
Input:  72
Input:  71
Input:  70
Input:  69
Input:  68
Input:  67
Input:  66
Input:  65
Input:  64
Input:  63
Input:  62
Input:  61
Input:  60
Input:  59
Input:  58
Input:  57
Input:  56
Input:  55
Input:  54
Input:  53
Input:  52
Input:  51
Input:  50
Input:  49
Input:  48
Input:  47
Input:  46
Input:  45
Input:  44
Input:  43
Input:  42
Input:  41
Input:  40
Input:  39
Input:  38
Input:  37
Input:  36
Input:  35
Input:  34
Input:  33
Input:  32
Input:  31
Input:  30
Input:  29
Input:  28
Input:  27
Input:  26
Input:  25
Input:  24
Input:  23
Input:  22
Input:  21
Input:  20
Input:  19
Input:  18
Input:  17
Input:  16
Input:  15
Input:  14
Input:  13
Input:  12
Input:  11
Input:  10
Input:  9
Input:  8
Input:  7
Input:  6
Input:  5
Input:  4
Input:  3
Input:  2
Input:  1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:31 +0x179

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc00004e070, 0xc00005c060)
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:9 +0xac
created by main.main
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:29 +0xc4

goroutine 7 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc00004e070, 0xc00005c060)
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:9 +0xac
created by main.main
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:29 +0xc4

goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc00004e070, 0xc00005c060)
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:9 +0xac
created by main.main
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:29 +0xc4

goroutine 9 [chan receive]:
main.worker(0xc00004e070, 0xc00005c060)
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:9 +0xac
created by main.main
        /Users/ianmitchell/go/src/github.com/iancmitchell/channel-recursion/main.go:29 +0xc4
exit status 2
```

I've tried this in a multitude of ways relying on channels like this and using wait groups but I cannot seem to get the process to work through all of the items and emit the outputs.

Comment: Can you describe your actual problem in a few words and show a minimal example displaying your problem?

Comment: Thanks Volker, I have simplified my examples and description.

Comment: @IanMitchell I have bad feelings that you have misunderstood the channel stuff. The deadlock problem is happening from line `element, more := <-input`. This statement gives you 2 values (current value from chan and if you successfully read from the channel then the 2nd value is true otherwise false). It does not tell you whether there is more values in the channel or not.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Are you sure about that? I was following the example in the official tour of go here: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4. It said that the second value will tell if there are no more values to receive and the channel is closed.

Comment: @IanMitchell key here is *and the channel is closed*. It tells you if it *cannot read* from the channel. If the channel is **not** closed and there are no more values, it just blocks.

Comment: @IanMitchell explain this https://play.golang.org/p/0QJOM0WdfDC.

Comment: I see now @ShudiptaSharma and Adrian. So this workflow will only work if the channel is explicitly closed at the right time. Adjusting the IF statement in the worker function that checks if emelent != 0 by adding an ELSE statement that closes the channels seems to fix the problem. Would that be the way you recommend solving this or is there a better way?

Comment: func worker should range over the input channel an not close it. Your idea of  "checking each time if there are more elements to receive" does not work that ways as Shudipta correctly noted. Channels simply do not work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go. First, note some problems resides in your code. Then fix them.

- As [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) said, read from a channel that is already closed or that has no element. In your worker func, you are doing that. This is happening when you are reading elements from the input channel after closing the input channel by another worker.

  ```golang
  func worker(input chan int, output chan<- int) {
      defer close(input)
      ...
      for {
          element, more := <-input
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  So, why are you not closing the input channel once all the workers finish?
- After solving the problem with your input channel another one will arise when you are trying to read from the output channel. Moreover, you are not sending anything on the output channel. If you do not need that channel, then why you are using this one. And also this output channel is unbuffered (channel of size 0 and send-receive should be at the same time otherwise deadlock situation will arise). See, buffered vs. unbuffered from [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) and [here](https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering). Maybe there are more helpful docs out there on the web. Thanks to my friend [Nightfury1204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6878708/nightfury1204) for the first link about buffered vs. unbuffered channel from his [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170157/7016115).

  ```golang
  outputChannel := make(chan int) // unbuffered, no size is defined
  ...
  for elem := range outputChannel {
      fmt.Println("Output: ", elem)
  }
  ```

  So, if you want to send something to the output channel, then the logic is your own. For example, you can send something after finishing your input channel processing in the workers. In that case, declare your output channel as buffered one having length 4 (since 4 workers you are running). After completing all your workers close your output channel and then read.

  ```golang
  outputChannel := make(chan int, 4) // buffered
  ...
  // after finishing all your workers
  close(outputChannel)
  for elem := range outputChannel {
      fmt.Println("Output: ", elem)
  }
  ```

> As a note, use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) from `"sync"` package to wait for
>   a collection of goroutines to finish.

See the example below:
https://play.golang.org/p/WAqwyR0ggNN

```golang
import "fmt"
import "sync"

func main() {
    inputChannel := make(chan int, 1)
    outputChannel := make(chan int, 4)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(4)

    inputChannel <- 100
    numWorkers := 4
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                select {
                case element := <-inputChannel:
                    fmt.Println("Input: ", element)
                    element--
                    if element != 0 {
                        inputChannel <- element
                    }
                default:
                    outputChannel<-0
                    fmt.Println("All Jobs Processed", len(outputChannel))
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(inputChannel)
    close(outputChannel)
    for elem := range outputChannel {
        fmt.Println("Output: ", elem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ShudiptaSharma. This is very helpful. Thanks for taking all the time to put that together.