# Worker pool pattern - deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, design-patterns, concurrency, goroutine

*Wait for task* pattern is the base pattern for pooling pattern. gobyexample [code](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) looks wrong, because this code is using buffered channels.

---

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

// pooling: You are a manager and you hire a team of employees. None of the new
// employees know what they are expected to do and wait for you to provide work.
// When work is provided to the group, any given employee can take it and you
// don't care who it is. The amount of time you wait for any given employee to
// take your work is unknown because you need a guarantee that the work your
// sending is received by an employee.
func pooling() {
    jobCh := make(chan int)     // signalling data on channel with guarantee - unbuffered
    resultCh := make(chan int)  // signalling data on channel with guarantee - unbuffered

    workers := runtime.NumCPU() // 4 workers
    for worker := 0; worker < workers; worker++ {
        go func(emp int) {
            var p int
            for p = range jobCh {
                fmt.Printf("employee %d : recv'd signal : %d\n", emp, p) // do the work
            }
            fmt.Printf("employee %d : recv'd shutdown signal\n", emp) // worker is signaled with closed state channel
            resultCh <- p * 2
        }(worker)
    }

    const jobs = 6
    for jobNum := 1; jobNum <= jobs; jobNum++ {
        jobCh <- jobNum
        fmt.Println("manager : sent signal :", jobNum)
    }

    close(jobCh)
    fmt.Println("manager : sent shutdown signal")

    for a := 1; a <= jobs; a++ {  //cannot range on 'resultCh'
        fmt.Println("Result received: ", <-resultCh)
    }
    fmt.Println("-------------------------------------------------------------")
}
func main() {
    pooling()
}
```

---

manager(`pooling()`) is not receiving all six results, from 4 workers(employees), as shown below,

```
$ uname -a 
Linux user 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ 
$ go version
go version go1.14.1 linux/amd64
$
$ go install github.com/myhub/cs61a
$ 
$ 
$ bin/cs61a 
manager : sent signal : 1
manager : sent signal : 2
manager : sent signal : 3
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 3
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 4
manager : sent signal : 4
manager : sent signal : 5
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 5
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 6
manager : sent signal : 6
manager : sent shutdown signal
employee 3 : recv'd shutdown signal
employee 2 : recv'd signal : 2
Result received:  12
employee 0 : recv'd signal : 1
employee 0 : recv'd shutdown signal
employee 2 : recv'd shutdown signal
Result received:  2
Result received:  4
employee 1 : recv'd shutdown signal
Result received:  0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!


goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.pooling()
        /home/../src/github.com/myhub/cs61a/Main.go:40 +0x25f
main.main()
        /home/../src/github.com/myhub/cs61a/Main.go:45 +0x20
$
$
$ bin/cs61a 
manager : sent signal : 1
employee 0 : recv'd signal : 1
manager : sent signal : 2
manager : sent signal : 3
manager : sent signal : 4
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 2
manager : sent signal : 5
manager : sent signal : 6
employee 2 : recv'd signal : 4
employee 2 : recv'd shutdown signal
employee 0 : recv'd signal : 5
manager : sent shutdown signal
Result received:  8
employee 0 : recv'd shutdown signal
Result received:  10
employee 1 : recv'd signal : 3
employee 1 : recv'd shutdown signal
Result received:  6
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 6
employee 3 : recv'd shutdown signal
Result received:  12
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.pooling()
        /home/user/../github.com/myhub/cs61a/Main.go:40 +0x25f
main.main()
        /home/user/../github.com/myhub/cs61a/Main.go:45 +0x20
```

---

**Edit:**

As per @Mark comments, moving `resultCh <- p * 2` into the loop gives below deadlock, which makes sense, because all goroutines are blocked. does buffered channel(of `resultCh`) help resolve this problem? but buffered channel does not signal data with guarantee..

```
$ go install github.com/myhub/cs61a
$ bin/cs61a 
manager : sent signal : 1
manager : sent signal : 2
manager : sent signal : 3
manager : sent signal : 4
employee 1 : recv'd signal : 2
employee 2 : recv'd signal : 3
employee 0 : recv'd signal : 1
employee 3 : recv'd signal : 4
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.pooling()
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:33 +0xfb
main.main()
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:46 +0x20

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.pooling.func1(0xc00001e0c0, 0xc00001e120, 0x0)
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:24 +0x136
created by main.pooling
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:20 +0xb7

goroutine 7 [chan send]:
main.pooling.func1(0xc00001e0c0, 0xc00001e120, 0x1)
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:24 +0x136
created by main.pooling
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:20 +0xb7

goroutine 8 [chan send]:
main.pooling.func1(0xc00001e0c0, 0xc00001e120, 0x2)
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:24 +0x136
created by main.pooling
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:20 +0xb7

goroutine 9 [chan send]:
main.pooling.func1(0xc00001e0c0, 0xc00001e120, 0x3)
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:24 +0x136
created by main.pooling
        /home/user/../myhub/cs61a/Main.go:20 +0xb7
$
$
$
```

---

1. Why is `pooling()` not able to receive results from all workers?
2. Manager is receiving only 4 results out of 6. One of the result received is zero (`Result received:  0`), data sent on `resultCh` is always supposed to be non-zero,  Why does `resultCh` receive zero value? It looks like `resultCh` is closed.

*Note: Correct working of `resultCh` is not part of the responsibility of worker pool pattern. Worker pool pattern only ensure the work is submitted to employee successfully using `jobCh`*

Comment: I tried running your code in go playground and it ran just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/6NzvjL8mKX5

Comment: In terms of your 2nd question, you see when the `jobCh` is closed, then the execution does not go through the for loop in the goroutine. As a result the value of `p` var is remains 0 (initialized as 0). So you are getting result as `2*0 = 0`.

Comment: can you take a look at this one ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262858/is-it-possible-to-add-items-to-a-go-channel-while-processing/61279179#61279179

Comment: Workers should write to the result channel `resultCh <- p * 2` inside the job loop, not outside it. Also, close job channel after receiving all results, not before.

Comment: please forgive my prev comments. But I think i know the reasons. If you believe, then I can share my thoughts. But before that take a look and differentiate https://play.golang.org/p/q2U60PSPXAd with your program and please let us know.

Comment: @Mark Query edited with your suggested changes... Closing `jobCh` after `resultCh` in `main()` does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

> Why is pooling() not able to receive results from all workers?

The loop within the goroutine(s) (`for p = range jobCh`) will process all requests. However the code that sends to `resultCh` is outside of the loop so will only be executed once (after the loop has finnished) within each go routine.

This is as per @Marks comment; your response about scope is correct but irrelevant. The for loop will iterate through the items on the channel; when the channel is closed the loop ends and `p` will contain the value processed on the last iteration (if any) and that is sent to `resultCh`.

This means that `resultCh` will be sent one value for each go routine (four values in your case based upon the comment in your code). If you want to publish a value to `resultCh` for every value reveived on `jobCh` then you need to move the send into the loop ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bCHGm6yciPK)):

```
var p int
for p = range jobCh {
    fmt.Printf("employee %d : recv'd signal : %d\n", emp, p) // do the work
    resultCh <- p * 2
}
fmt.Printf("employee %d : recv'd shutdown signal\n", emp)
```

> Manager is receiving only 4 results out of 6. One of the result received is zero (Result received:  0), data sent on resultCh is always supposed to be non-zero, Why does resultCh receive zero value? It looks like resultCh is closed.

You cannot predict how many jobs each go routine will process (and the logs show that this differed between your two runs). From your log we can tell which routine processed which jobs::

```
Employee 0: 1
Employee 1: 
Employee 2: 2
Employee 3: 3, 4, 5, 6
```

You will note that Employee 1 did not process any jobs. This means that the employees loop `for p = range jobCh` terminated without ever assigning anything to `p` and, thus,  `resultCh <- p * 2` sent 0 (the default value for an int) to `resultCh` (as per the comment from @Shudipta Sharma).

Comment: Query edited with deadlock error, after moving `resultCh <- p * 2` into for-loop

Comment: Looks like I need fan-out pattern for such problem, when I need result back

Comment: The deadlock occurs because the loop retrieving the results (```for a := 1; a <= jobs; a++ {```) and the loop sending in jobs (```for jobNum := 1; jobNum <= jobs; jobNum++ {```) are running in the same go routine (as neither channel is buffered the workers all end up waiting for something to read from the results channel but this cannot happen until all jobs are submitted). Quickest fix is to move the loop that submits jobs into a go routine.